# error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd': Permission denied

Tags: python, installation, xlrd

I'm trying to install xlrd on mac 10.8.4 to be able to read excel files through python.

I have followed the instructions on http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf

I did this:

1. unzipped the folder to desktop
2. in terminal, cd to the unzipped folder
3. $ python setup.py install

This is what I get:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/__init__.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/biffh.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/book.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/compdoc.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/formatting.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/formula.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/info.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/licences.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/sheet.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/timemachine.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/xldate.py -> build/lib/xlrd
copying xlrd/xlsx.py -> build/lib/xlrd
creating build/lib/xlrd/doc
copying xlrd/doc/compdoc.html -> build/lib/xlrd/doc
copying xlrd/doc/xlrd.html -> build/lib/xlrd/doc
creating build/lib/xlrd/examples
copying xlrd/examples/namesdemo.xls -> build/lib/xlrd/examples
copying xlrd/examples/xlrdnameAPIdemo.py -> build/lib/xlrd/examples
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting scripts/runxlrd.py -> build/scripts-2.7
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/runxlrd.py from 644 to 755
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd': Permission denied
```

Why is permission denied? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `sudo python setup.py install`

the /Library folder needs root permission to be accessed.

Comment: Don't `sudo`! Use the `--user` flag

Comment: In my case (OpenELEC) there is no sudo, so the --user flag is what did  it!

Answer (score 155):

Try `python setup.py install --user`

You shouldn't use `sudo` as suggested above for two reasons:

1. You're allowing arbitrary untrusted code off the internet to be run as root
2. Passing the `--user` flag to `python setup.py install` will install the package to a user-owned directory. Your normal non-root user won't be able to access the files installed by `sudo pip` or `sudo python setup.py`

Comment: if I already installed packages with root there, can I just change the permissions with `chown -R username /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` or what do you recommend?

Comment: Not something I've had to deal with, and I wouldn't take my word on that anyway - ask it as a new question and see what other people have to say :-) Maybe leave a link to your Q here when you do

Answer (score 4):

Try in a `virtualenv`:

- sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
- mkvirtualenv
- workon
- python setup.py install