# setuptools easy_install mac error

Tags: python, macos, setuptools, easy-install

I'm trying to setup easy_install on my mac.
But I'm getting the following error.

> Installing Setuptools running install Checking .pth file support in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ error: can't create or remove files
>   in install directory
>   The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-789.pth'
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: What sequence of commands do you run? (i.e. which way are you installing easy_install?)

Comment: sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try again using `sudo python ...` to be able to write to '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: You need to sudo the `python` command, not the `curl` command. Note that you must absolutely be trusting the people at bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py to run such commands in that way.

Comment: This worked except for that command 'easy_install' is still not found

Comment: And in a new terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

Try [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), its somewhat similar to rbenv and is easier to remove if you don't need it. Also, you can play with different versions of pythons without tinkering the system dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python` for access related issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "sudo" before "python setup.py ..." in the install.sh.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `--user` flag (instead of `sudo` or `pyenv`):

```
$ easy_install --user -U ...
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23789994/21115).